# how to find a user available online by checking two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables 'Users' and 'Friends':

```
Table: Users(username,email,location,online_status)
Table: Friends(Friend_rq_from,Friend_request_to,status)
```

'Users' table is for number of registered users in a website

and 'Friends' table for individual users for maintaing thier friends..

i want to count eg: mithun's friends from 'Friends' table(1 indicating they are friends in Friends table) who are online in Users table..(1 indicate online in 'users' table)

its a little bit difficult for me because, 'Friends' table have 2 fields which 'mithun' can be in 'Friend_rq_from' field or 'Friend_request_to' field...
how to find this?

NB: Friend_rq_from: Indicating who start a friend request,
    Friend_request_to: Indicating to whom a request sent(or who is waiting to accept)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct u.username)
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Friends f
ON (u.username = f.Friend_rq_from AND f.Friend_rq_to='mithun' AND f.status=1)
OR (u.username = f.Friend_rq_to AND f.Friend_rq_from='mithun' AND f.status=1)
WHERE u.online_status = 1 AND u.username <> 'mithun'
```

Comment: Stefano Crespi is der any additional check in Friends table for they are friends or not(using Friends table status)

Comment: What's the actual meaning of the status column in the friends table?

Comment: status field in friends table indicate they are friends

Comment: adjusted to take into account friends.status